# getting Image ThumbNail in Android

Tags: android, image, thumbnails

I need Thumbnail of an image . I only know about the name of image which is stored in SD card . Can anyone help me.

Comment: what you wanna do with that thumbnail

Comment: I needed the thumbnail because I kept getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when putting all image URIs directly in a GridView.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this.

```
final int THUMBSIZE = 64;

Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), 
                    THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
```

[Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html) for more details.

Comment: What is `imagePath` ?

Comment: It is image path name stored in sdcard.

Comment: if you are using an Uri for the image you can get the path using, for example imageUri.getPath()

Comment: Right to the point and very useful indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Using [`MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html) you can query and get two kinds of thumbnails: MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail MICRO_KIND: 96 x 96 thumbnail.

The advantage of using this call is that the thumbnails are cached by the MediaStore. So retrieval would be faster if the thumbnail was previously created.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] imageData = null;

try
{

final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

Float width = new Float(imageBitmap.getWidth());
Float height = new Float(imageBitmap.getHeight());
Float ratio = width/height;
imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, (int)(THUMBNAIL_SIZE * ratio), THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
imageData = baos.toByteArray();

}
catch(Exception ex) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like HQ thumbnails, so use [RapidDecoder][1] library. It is simple as follow:

```
import rapid.decoder.BitmapDecoder;
...
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapDecoder.from(getResources(), R.drawable.image)
                             .scale(width, height)
                             .useBuiltInDecoder(true)
                             .decode();
```

Don't forget to use builtin decoder if you want to scale down less than 50% and a HQ result.