# Loading smaller version of an image for performance Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide, bitmapfactory

I have an image (1.84MB) to load and I want to load a smaller version of it to gain time, I also don't want to store a smaller version of it. For info, these files are located in a removable SD card, and I need to load a lot, thats why I want to optimize it, as it takes too much time for the moment...

I red the [load large bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#java) documentation. I previously used Glide to load the full image.

After some test, I get this statistics:
Glide load (1.84MB):    244'361'667 ns
Bitmap load (scale 1):  370'811'511 ns
Bitmap load (scale 4):  324'403'386 ns
Bitmap load (scale 8):  269'223'073 ns
Thumbnail load:         245'250'729 ns

Which means I get a slightly longer time with Bitmap while loading a 8 times smaller image, and I don't get why.

Here is my code:

load with glide:

```
private void loadGlide(Car c) {
DocumentFile makerDir = contentDirectory.findFile(getMakerById(c.getMakerId()).getName());
DocumentFile carPhoto = makerDir.findFile(c.getFilename());
if(carPhoto == null) {
    Log.d("test", c.getFilename() + " problem");
} else {
    Log.d("test", carPhoto.exists() + "");
}
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        goToEdit(c.getId());
    }
});
// standard loading
Glide.with(img.getContext()).load(carPhoto.getUri()).into(img);
resultList.addView(img);
```

}

load with bitmap:

```
private void scaledLoad(Car c, int scale) {
DocumentFile makerDir = contentDirectory.findFile(getMakerById(c.getMakerId()).getName());
DocumentFile carPhoto = makerDir.findFile(c.getFilename());
Bitmap b = null;
//Decode image size
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = scale;
// convert DocumentFile to File
File image = new File("image_path");
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(image);
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);
    fis.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(b != null) {
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageBitmap(b);
    resultList.addView(img);
}
```

}

I also tried to load [thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110163/getting-image-thumbnail-in-android):

```
private void loadThumbnail() {
Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("filepath"),
        816, 612);
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageBitmap(ThumbImage);
resultList.addView(img);
```

}

And here is the test code if you want:

```
long t0 = System.nanoTime();
scaledLoad(c, 1);
// or
loadGlide(c);
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
t1 = (t1-t0);
Log.d("test", "t1:" + t1);
```

If you can answer me or give me any other alternative to load underscaled images from SD card FAST, you are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, what is "underscaled" mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Glide you can use the function "override(width,height)" to load resized image into the imageView.

This blogs explains how to do it :  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-image-resizing-scaling#imageresizingwithoverridexy