# How to load image (from sdcard) faster in thumbnail size?

Tags: android, gridview, gallery, universal-image-loader

I want to make a grid view to show thumbnail of photos in folder in sdcard. 
Image resolution is 3264x2448. I use Notras Universal Image Loader lib with config:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.stub)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher).cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(options).build();
```

And getView() in my custom Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = (ImageView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,
                parent, false);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    mImageLoader.displayImage(mListData.get(position), imageView, options);

    return imageView;
}
```

But it load image too slow. **So please help me to load thumbnail image faster. I don't want to display high quality image, I just want to display fast.**

Thanks in advance.

UIL version: 1.8.4
Android version tested on: 2.3.3

Comment: use a viewholder for smooth scrolling and performance. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: @Raghunandan Because my item layout just contain an ImageView so I don't use ViewHolder, I think it's not make image load slower.

Comment: @VAdaihiep can you please tell me how to load sdcard images in Universal Image Loader, i tried but error shows like              UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/mnt/sdcard/images/Adhisayam_2012/DSC_0122.jpg]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))             please help me..

Comment: Use very simple: 
universalImageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView); 

I think your imageUri do not have "file://" at head. It should be file://mnt/sdcard/images/Adhisayam_2012/DSC_0122.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.discCacheExtraOptions(800, 800, CompressFormat.PNG, 0)` in configuration. You can vary value "800" depending maximum dimension of device.

Comment: cacheInMemory() and cacheOnDisc() method is deprecated .. so how perform caching ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the thumbnail:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                         getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri,
                         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                         (BitmapFactory.Options) null );
```

There are two types of thumbnails available:
MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail
MICRO_KIND: 96 x 96 thumbnail

OR use queryMiniThumbnail with almost same parameters to get the path of the thumbnail.

```
Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(
                         getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri,
                         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                         null );
if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
 cursor.moveToFirst();//**EDIT**
 String uri = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA ) );
}
```

you can use this uri in imageloader to view thumbnails

[Reference and detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548645/get-thumbnail-uri-path-of-the-image-stored-in-sd-card-android)

Comment: Thank you, I just try it but selectedImageUri is a String but this method require a id in long type. Any suggest?

Comment: *mImageLoader.displayImage(uri, imageView, options);*
here uri is Image URI (i.e. it can be web url or "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png").

Comment: Which method is actually need id of long type? Please explain

Comment: I mean selectedImageURI in here: Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnail(
                         getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri,
                         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND,
                         null );
It can be a long or Uri but I dont know how to get Uri from a file's path, like /mnt/sdcard/ABC.JPG?

Comment: You can give uri also instead of long id. **public static final Cursor queryMiniThumbnails (ContentResolver cr, Uri uri, int kind, String[] projection)**